# Two divs fill in same line

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div >
        <div class="dash">
            <span>Soba</span>
            <p>xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xx2323232x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to create a sample dashboard. The left div is for elements and the right div is for content details. I'm having trouble with display items and keeping two divs straight at the same time.

[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X21HD.png)

Comment: Do you want them to be same height ?

Comment: Not really. I just want them to be straight in top row.

Comment: style="display: flex". put this code inside 2nd div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, You need to add `vertical-align:top` to the both columns. I have created a fiddle below. Hope it helps.

Please click on "Run Code Snippet" them expand it to see " full view "

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.dash {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 13%;
  height: 800px;
  border-style: dashed;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 83%;
  height: auto;
  border-style: dashed;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="dash">
    <span>Soba</span>
    <p>xxxx</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>xxxx</p>
    <p>xxxx</p>
    <p>xxxx</p>
    <p>xx2323232x</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, please mark it as a answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add flex display to root div This might help:

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div  style="display:flex">
        <div class="dash">
            <span>Soba</span>
            <p>xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xx2323232x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It work in someway but not effectively since flex force two div to have same height. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

steps:
1.Add parent class to you div
2.Apply flex display property

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.dash-wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="dash-wrapper">
        <div class="dash">
            <span>Soba</span>
            <p>xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xx2323232x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it work in someway but not effectively since flex force two div to have same height. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @FaizEming As you asked you required two div side by side & in straight line, this is what we have achieved here, what else require please share

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind and make it more specific next time.

Comment: @FaizEming - Please mark it as answer if it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I know many people have already answered but here i just added `vertical-align:top;` to the `.dash` also i've removed the `margin-top: 20px;` from `.dash` as well. So this is basically all your code with 2 lines difference. See the attached [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/iahmadhabibx/pen/MWwpmja)

Answer (score -1):

you just missed a **float option**. try this , it will solve your problem.
codepen link

> https://codepen.io/salmanaabir/pen/XWbMRmK

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.content{
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div >
        <div class="dash">
            <span>Soba</span>
            <p>xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xx2323232x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

With flex and `align-items:start;` you can solve it. Here is the code.

```css
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.parent-section{
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: start;
  -webkit-align-items: start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent-section">
        <div class="dash">
            <span>Soba</span>
            <p>xxxx</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xxxx</p>
                <p>xx2323232x</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
    width: 100%;
}
.dash{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13%;
    height: 800px;
    border-style: dashed;    
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 83%;
    height: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.dash-wrapper{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation how you came to this result. Thanks